# Decode formData from AngularJS in PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

Im using angular-file-upload to upload a file from website to db.

It is working nicely but I now want to upload the file to the db with the username.

Im attaching the username to formData during:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'php/uploadPic.php',
    formData: []
});

uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
    //console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
    formData = [{
        name: $scope.id
    }];
    item.formData.push(formData);
    console.log(formData);
};
```

I got this info from https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/issues/225

In the console `console.log(formData);` I get:

[image]

The name: "user1" is what I want to assign to $id in my PHP file.

I got the fromData into the PHP file because when I use `print_r($_POST);` and `print_r($_POST[0]);` I get the PHP response showing

```
`Array
(
    [0] => [object Object]
)`
```

and

```
`[object Object]`
```

Using the below statements as suggested I still get errors: 
    
    `$id = json_decode($_POST[0]['name']);
    $id1 = json_decode($_POST['name'][0]);
    $id2 = $_POST[0]['name'];
    $id3 = $POST['formData']->name;`

```
`
Illegal string offset 'name' in
Undefined index: name in
Illegal string offset 'name' in
Undefined index: formData in
`
```

Any ideas on how I can get $id = name in the array?

Thank you

Comment: There is no such key as `formdata.name`. What about `$_POST['formdata']->name`?

Comment: Hi. I still get the error Undefined index: formData when using $_POST['formdata']->name...

Comment: Because I'm not sure what is the structure of POST object, better do `print_r($_POST)` in your PHP file in order to see it.

Comment: Updated my question to show some more info. Please let me know if you need more detail to see whats going on. I think its something simple im missing..

Comment: just use json_decode($_POST['formData'][0]);

Comment: @JCom09 you didn;t tried  json_decode($_POST['formData'][0]);

Comment: Sorry I didnt add it into the above edit but still get an error: Undefined index: formData in...

Answer (score 0):

Wasnt posting data to PHP correctly.

Needed to use [0] when pushing

```
item.formData.push(formData[0]);
```

Then I can read the data in my PHP using

```
$id = $_POST['name'];
```